# Approximately 8.33% of men are colorblind. You survey 8 men from the population of a large city and count the number who are colorblind.

Tags: binomial-distribution

This question shows up in the binomial distribution chapter in my book.

g. How many men would you have to survey in order to be at least 95%
sure you would find at least $1$ who is colorblind?

Now I know that $P(X \geq 1) = 1 - P(X=0) = 1 - {8\choose0}.0833^0.9167^8 = 1 - .4986752922 = .5013247078$

But this is for a sample of 8 men. This question is asking me to find $n$ with $95$% confidence,

But this seems like a confidence interval question which I'm a little confused about since my book is about probability and not about statistics. Nothing like this shows up in my book, so I'm stuck. I feel like this is a "challenge" question.

Can someone give me a clue on what formula to use to deal with a question like this? Is this even a confidence interval question?

Thank You

Comment: The question doesn't make sense because it starts with "you survey $8$ men..." and then asks "how many men would you have to survey...". If this were a typical confidence interval question, it wouldn't have the sentence with the $8$.

Comment: @angryavian This could be one of the parts in a multi-part question. The actual question begins with "g.". Perhaps the OP forgot to filter out the redundant info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to solve
$1 - {n\choose0}(0.0833^0)(0.9167^n)\ge0.95$.

Comment: Forgive me, but when I plug in $86$ into the above, I get the following $1-({86 \choose 0} \cdot 0.0833^0 \cdot 0.9167^{86}) = .9994$ (approximately). I found that $n = 35$, is the minimum as $1-({35 \choose 0} \cdot 0.0833^0 \cdot 0.9167^{35}) = .9523$ (approximately). Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. I solved $1-\binom n10.9167^n\ge0.95$. That is the wrong inequality altogether. $n\ge35$ is absolutely correct.

Comment: ah okay, thank you for your help!